# Why is one Java thread only getting back half of the data inserted by another thread in SQLServer?

Tags: sql-server, multithreading, jdbc

In this specific scenario, I have two threads:

1. One is polling for new files on disk in a specific folder. It uses metadata from the file to insert jobs into the database (across multiple tables). Autocommit is set to false, and I am committing only at the end of the loop (assuming there are more than one file found at a time, it commits once per file).
2. Another thread is constantly polling for new "jobs" to process. It queries primarily against one table, but there are a couple of left joins. The query uses the `with (updlock, readpast)` table hints only on the primary table.

I have noticed that some of the jobs that come back are missing values for one or more of the left joins, but only for the first time (it causes a failure, which then triggers that job to be picked up again seconds later). I know for sure that the value is not actually null, because I have added log statements before and after each query that inserts the data. I have made sure that autocommit is disabled, and I only commit once all pieces of data are there.

One thing I have noticed though, which seems to be a pattern, is that the polling thread starts its query shortly before the other thread finishes. It could be one or two operations behind, or it could be just about to commit. It returns the result after the first thread commits (based on timestamps in my log).

I don't understand how this could happen. I have a `readpast` hint on the primary table, so it should not even come back in the query. But it comes back without the associated data from the joining table, which does not have any hints on it. If it took a few seconds to run (it's generally pretty quick though) it should theoretically encounter the locked row that was not committed yet, and just skip it.

Here is a simple example of the query that I am using to poll for new jobs.

```
SELECT distinct
  j.id,
  p.request_path,
  j.revision_id,
  j.status,
  j.creation_date,
  dr.dependent_revision_id
from incoming_jobs j WITH (updlock, readpast)
  left join file_paths p on j.revision_id = p.revision_id
  left join dependent_revisions dr on j.id = dr.job_id
where j.status in ('WAITING')
  and dr.dependent_revision_id is null
order by j.creation_date offset 0 rows fetch next 3 row only
```

In this case, there is a non-null value in `file_paths` for the job, but it comes back null anyhow. That value gets inserted immediately after the job is inserted into the `incoming_jobs` table by the other thread.

Comment: What transaction isolation level are you using?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I would assume whatever the default is. We never explicitly set anything on the Connection other than to turn autocommit off and on.

Comment: Then you're probably using `READ_COMMITTED`, which, depending on the exact changes done, might give you an inconsistent view. However without a [mre] that is hard to say for sure